# getting date from string in object

Tags: php, string, datetime

I save my dates as datetime in my db (e.g. 2013-09-23 15:00:00).

When I create an object I call this date by

```
$event->start
```

When I just echo it, I get the right value but it is a string and no longer a datetime.
That is why this won't work:

```
date_format('d-m-Y', $event->start)
```

To use date() I need a timestamp, which I don't have. What is a possible solution?

I tried this:

```
date_format(strtotime($event->startdate), 'd-m-Y')
```

But still getting 'Date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime'

SOLUTION

```
$dt = new DateTime($event->start);
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: @SeanJohnson you are right.

Comment: please try to find the answer or question in stack overflow first then ask the question to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which will give you a timestamp from a vaguely human readable date string. You can then use that in your `date_format` call, e.g.

```
$ts = strtotime($event->start);

if($ts !== FALSE)   // !== -1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.1.0
    $date = date_format("d-m-Y", $ts);
```

Comment: still getting the message saysing 'date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given' (see edit)

Comment: Oops, I thought `date_format` expected a timestamp, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime` to get datetime from a string

just try this

`echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($event->start))`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this.

Try this code.

```
$date = $event->start;
$my_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
echo $my_date;
```